# Tracing the reflected XSS attempts

Tags: php, xss

So, here is a piece of code I came across.

```
<?php

    $name = $_GET['name'];

    if (!empty($name)) {
            $name = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $name);    //line 1
            $name = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $name);    //line 2
            $name = urldecode($name);                   //line 3

            echo $name;

    }

    ?>
```

This code I found in one of the ethical hacking practicing frameworks named [bWAPP](http://www.itsecgames.com/) at security level 1. The potential solution to bypass this technique is to `URL encode` the XSS string twice.

Let's assume my XSS string is

```
<script>alert('XSS');</script>       //checkpoint alpha
```

Then, encoding it once should give me

```
%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27XSS%27%29%3C%2fscript%3E  //checkpoint beta
```

**PROBLEM 1:** 
If I trace it down, on line 1 and 2 nothing happens. But on line 3 it gets decoded. And so, the resultant string I get back becomes `checkpoint alpha`. So, when I echo it, I should get an alert poped up.

**CONTRADICTION 1:**
Nothing like this happens and I just get the `checkpoint alpha` displayed in clear text.

**PROBLEM 2:**
When, I double encode it,(which is the potential solution to this problem), I get,

```
%253Cscript%253Ealert%2528%2527XSS%2527%2529%253C%252fscript%253E
```

Now, this statement again passes through line 1 and 2, and on stumbling upon line 3, it gets decoded to `checkpoint beta` and gets echoed.

**CONTRADICTION 2:**
When it gets echoed, I should get `checkpoint beta` in clear text but Suddenly the browser pops up the alert box with XSS working perfectly.

I am new in this field and currently trying to clear my basic concepts related to web development. Please pardon my incorrect statement formation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When PHP retrieves the GET parameter with `$name = $_GET['name']`, it performs an implicit URL decoding. PHP doesn't require you to decode an URL parameter yourself.

These both result in the exact same value for `$name`:

```
http://yourapp/?name=<script>alert(1);</script>
http://yourapp/?name=%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2fscript%3E
```

So even if `<` looks like `%3c` in your URL, it will be stored as a literal `<` in `$name`. In consequence, the `str_replace()` part correctly recognizes `<` and `>` and filters these characters out, thereby preventing XSS.

The vulnerable part is the explicit `urldecode()` at the end.

If you provide the URL `http://yourapp/?name=%253c`, then variable `$name` will literally contain`%3c` (that's three characters) and the `str_replace()` functions will ignore it because neither of `%`, `3`, `c` looks like an angle bracket. Then, in the end, `urldecode()` unnecessarily performs another decoding and turns the sequence `%3c` into a literal `<` after it has already passed the replace filter.

If it's still a bit unclear to you, replace `$name = $_GET['name']` with this:

```
$name = urldecode('%253Cscript%253Ealert%25281%2529%253C%252fscript%253E')
```

You will see that this has the same effect as providing the string as the URL parameter and it shows that two urldecodes are redundant.

Comment: So, in short, php recognised `%3C` and `<` same. And it stored it as `<` ???

Comment: @M.S.P Yes, but only if it comes from a URL parameter, as is the case with `$_GET['name']`.

Comment: That's what I tried to say, but you have put it more clearly than I did! :D

Comment: Well, that clears both the contradictions! Thank you @Arminius

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I am not a php developer (or a developer at all), but I tested this.

tldr: $_GET['name'] urldecodes the parameter name

I used your code but put an:

```
echo $name;
```

At every line.

I tested the following:

- <test>, the $name parameter starts as  and ends with escaped characters
- %3Ctest%3E, the $name parameter starts as  after the $_GET, so immediatly the parameter is already urldecoded once
- %253Ctest%253E, the $name parameter starts as %3Ctest%3E after the $_GET so is decoded once. Then the validation fails and the second decode decodes the parameter to

To answer your contradictions:

**Contradiction 1** look at what you actually get back using firebug or a proxy or http requester. Your browser says it shows you  but what it actually got was < test > and interpreted that to . This can be confusing but the browser got your escaped scentence back.

**Contradiction 2** Beta is encoded once, gets decoded once at the start request ($_GET), then the < and > get changed to < and >.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your answer, but, I am not able to understand what you are trying to convey. Kindly, make it clear.

Comment: @M.S.P I changed it a bit as I made a mistake in C2 and stack doesn't like html to much :D. What part is unclear, so I can explain better